# ansible playbook inline to add multiple lines

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i got following pb to add multiple lines to chrony.conf

```
- name: add line
  lineinfile:
    backup: no
    backrefs: no
    state: present
    path: "{{ file_path }}"
    insertafter: "{{ line.replace_with }}"
    line: "{{ line.line_to_add }}"
  with_items:
    - { search: "{{ line.replace_with }}", add: "{{ line.line_to_add }}" }


in my vars files I got it like this

line:
  line_to_add:
    - "server ntp1.domain.com iburst"
    - "server ntp2.domain.com iburst"
    - "server ntp3.domain.com iburst"
```

but the change put all 3 ntp servers in one line instead of 3.

any idea?

---

when i change my yml to

```
- name: add line
  lineinfile:
    backup: no
    backrefs: no
    state: present
    path: "{{ file_path }}"
    #regexp: '^(\s*)[#]?{{ item.search }}(: )*'
    insertafter: "{{ line.replace_with }}"
    line: "{{ item }}"
    create: true
  loop: "{{ line.line_to_add }}"
  with_items:
   - { search: "{{ line.replace_with }}", add: "{{ line.line_to_add }}" }
```

I get suplicate loop in task: items

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop for this to iterate each line in the line.line_to_add variable. I also assumed that you have another line.replace_with variable.

```
- name: Example of multiple lines
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    line:
      line_to_add:
        - "server ntp1.domain.com iburst"
        - "server ntp2.domain.com iburst"
        - "server ntp3.domain.com iburst"
      replace_with:
        - test_line

  tasks:
    - name: add line
      lineinfile:
        backup: no
        backrefs: no
        state: present
        path: test_file
        insertafter: "{{ line.replace_with }}"
        line: "{{ item }}"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ line.line_to_add }}"
```

Gives:

```
server ntp1.domain.com iburst
server ntp2.domain.com iburst
server ntp3.domain.com iburst
```

Comment: not sure why my pb is getting error. I am using vars file

Comment: - name: add line
  lineinfile:
    backup: no
    backrefs: no
    state: present
    path: "{{ file_path }}"
    #regexp: '^(\s*)[#]?{{ item.search }}(: )*'
    insertafter: "{{ line.replace_with }}"
    line: "{{ item }}"
    create: true
  loop: "{{ line.line_to_add }}"
  with_items:
    - { search: "{{ line.replace_with }}", add: "{{ line.line_to_add }}" }

Comment: Can you update your question above and add it as code to make it more readable? Also, provide what is the error you're getting.

Comment: By just scanning it i see `loop and with_items` together. You must choose either loop alone or with_items alone and not both.

Comment: so how do i put it?

Comment: i need to add the new lines after line.replace_with

Comment: Check my example. the loop is iterating on line.line_to_add which is defined in vars.